# Crm 2013 how to create multiple custom entities

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

What are the possible "supported" ways to create multiple Custom Entities in CRM 2013?

I know we can create entities by opening the solution and create one entity at a time, but looking for an efficient way to do the task.

Thank You for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Do it manually via the CRM website.
2. Edit the Solution File.  Solutions are exported and imported as a zipped file containing resources, and an xml document containing the configuration.  Correctly editing the xml file to include new entities would result in the creation of said entities.  Import the edited solution file to create the new entities.
3. Perform the calls using the SDK, most likely C#.  See [this for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509014.aspx).

Comment: Thank You Daryl. I would prefer to follow third option.

Comment: @KiranXyz What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Daryl, We wanted to build a pilot project into CRM 2013 of our existing .net registration application. As a start I wanted to replicate the data model; pick the SQL tables and create CRM entities; our LOB has lot of image processing, bulk scanning attached to each registration record and the system has to exchange messages with other consumers.